# Class AB amplifier Design

Tags: amplifier, design

I want to design a Class AB amplifier as seen below. But, I don't know how to find the values of the resistors and capacitors. I have found the KVL around the closed loop containing the diodes and resistors to find R; where  R = (Vcc - 1.4V)/(2*I) but I dont know how to determinet I. Is there any way to find I, also my load resistor is 4 ohms. Thanks[image]

Comment: bypassing the diodes with capacitors can improve the tolerance on the biassing current. Note that this schematic is more of a sketch for discussion, than a design for a high fidelity audio amplifier.

Comment: I should be significantly larger than the base currents of TR1 and TR2 -like 5-10x larger.

Comment: As the transistors heat up, a positive feedback event will occur; the transistors will thermally run away, and destroy themselves unless enough lumpd Re is in the emitters. Play it safe, and insert 1_Ohm in each emitter. Or 10_Ohms for small transistors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For basing diodes, 1-5mA range is quite acceptable.

But does not finish with this. You need some other info:

As you might know, output current passes through collectors. So each output transistor's base will need a current of \$I_B = I_C / \beta \$. Thus, **R1 and R2 should also allow enough base current for output transistors.**

- Determine output power (\$P_O\$) and calculate output voltage (\$V_O\$) and current (\$I_{O}\$). Also, this circuit has a unity voltage gain:

$$V_{O-rms} = \sqrt{P_O \cdot 4\Omega} \ ,\ \ \ \ V_{O-pk} = V_{o-rms} \cdot 1.41$$
$$I_{O-rms} = \sqrt{P_O / 4\Omega} \ ,\ \ \ \ I_{O-pk} = I_{o-rms} \cdot 1.41$$

Select proper transistors having enough \$V_{CE}\$ for \$V_{O-pk}\$ and \$I_C\$ for \$I_{O-pk}\$. Select Vcc for enough voltage swing: \$V_{CC} = 2\cdot V_{o-pk} + 1V\$

- From datasheets, calculate required base currents from \$I_B = I_C / \beta\$. Note that \$\beta\$ value can be quite low (e.g. between 10 and 25) for high output currents.
- Calulate R1 and R4 for diode bias current and transistor base current.

Input coupling cap is calculated from minimum input frequency (\$f_L\$). If we assume input impedance is parallel equivalent of R1 and R2 (say \$R_i = R1 || R2\$) then input coupling cap is \$Ci = 1/(2\pi f_L R_i)\$. If you don't have any info, put a 10uF electrolytic and test.

Output coupling cap is also calculated from minimum input frequency: \$C_o = 1/(2\pi f_L \cdot 4\Omega)\$. If you don't have any info, put a 2200uF electrolytic *(+ to common emitter, - to load resistance)* and test.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where did you get 1-5mA range as I would need to refer to it.

Comment: @Swag96 Any small-signal general purpose or fast switching silicon diodes serve good performance at that level of bias currents. For example, I recommend you to use 1N4148 (or LL4148 which is the SMD version) diodes because they have good performance at high temperatures and you can see from the [datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/85557/ll4148.pdf) that 1-10mA range is quite linear, so you can select any bias point on that range (e.g. for If = 3mA, Vf = 0.7V).